# Is there a way to show the date (in addition to time) in the OS X lock screen?

Tags: mac, macos, settings

This is what the default OS X lock screen, (if you have it set to require password on wake from sleep etc.), looks like:

[image]

By default it seems to only show the time in the top right-hand corner.

It would be great to have today's date handy as a reference in the screen as well - just like you can configure it.

Without finding a third-party lock screen app (that costs money), is there a command or setting to include the date in the OS X default lock screen?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I'm updated to the latest consumer-available revision at present, 10.9.2.

Comment: Not trying to sound mean, but why would you want to do this?

Comment: ^ I have my mac configured to require password immediately upon wake (from sleep/screen saver etc), so end up using the default lock screen a lot for quick reference if need be. Date would be great to be able to refer to lightning quick like you can the time.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, which worked for me, was the following crontab entry, in root's crontab:

```
0 0 * * * defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow LoginwindowText "The date is `date '+%B %d, %Y'`"
```

This sets a message on the lock screen, including the date.  It isn't as slick as including the date with the time in the corner, but it has the advantage of working at all (I couldn't get @konqui's answer to work for me), and it doesn't require installing any 3rd-party software.

If anyone is interested, I detailed the procedure in [more depth on my blog](http://kaeding.name/articles/2015/02/08/how-to-display-the-date-on-the-os-x-lock-screen/), but the essence of the solution is posted here.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Live Wallpaper App](https://itunes.apple.com/tr/app/live-wallpaper/id531123879?mt=12) and setup it as a wallpaper which supports clock on wallpaper. It's not free but it's not expensive too.

Answer (score 0):

I know your Problem, You would like to have the same Date/Time Format when the Mac is locked as when you are logged in? wouldn't you.

I once found a solution on the Apple Community Forum, Sadly i don't remeber if it worked for me. But i will give it another try when i'm home.

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/message/16630967#16630967

---

Here is solution used to change time to 24-hour format on Mac OS Login and Lock screens. I am running OS X 10.8.2 localized in Sweden.

1. To enable Swedish time format on Login screen run following command from Terminal:

   sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences AppleLocale "sv_SE"
2. To enable Swedish time format on Lock screen do the following:
    a. Enable Root User (how to do see below)
    b. Logout
    c. Login as root
    d. In System Preferences -> Date & Time -> Clock check Use 24-hour clock
    e. Login as standard user
    f. Disable Root as User (how to do see below)

To enable Root User:

System Preferences
-> User & Groups
Click the lock to make changes  (admin password)
Login Options
Jonn
Open Directory Utility
Click the lock to make changes  (admin password)

Menu -> Edit -> Enable Root User

Type Password two times

To disable Root User

System Preferences
-> User & Groups
Click the lock to make changes  (admin password)
Login Options
Jonn
Open Directory Utility
Click the lock to make changes  (admin password)

Menu -> Edit -> Disable Root User

Comment: sorry, how does your answer display the DATE in the lock screen